# makeStyles Items of Stack including their spacing @mui

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, material-ui

I want to change my background color when hover each item but I want to change the spacing area bgColor too.
any idea?
[image]

```
<Stack spacing={4} divider={<Divider variant={`fullWidth`} orientation={`horizontal`} flexItem/>}>
                    {announcements.map((announcement, key) =>
                        (
                            <Item className={classes.items}>
                                <Details />
                            </Item>
                        ))}
                </Stack>
```

but the result is:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can change the background color of the spacing area between items in a Stack component in Material-UI (@mui), you can use the `sx` prop and target the `gap` property of the Stack

```
import { Stack, makeStyles } from '@mui/material';

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  item: {
    // Set the background color of each item when hovered
    '&:hover': {
      backgroundColor: '[color code here]',
    },
  },
  gap: {
    // Set the background color of the spacing area between items when hovered
    '& > *:not(:last-child)': {
      backgroundColor: '[color code here]',
    },
  },
}));
```

**Your Stack component**

```
<Stack direction="column" spacing={2} sx={{ gap: 2 }}/>}>
                    {announcements.map((announcement, key) =>
                        (
                            <Item className={classes.items}>
                                <Details />
                            </Item>
                        ))}
                </Stack>
```

**Try this Example**

```
function MyComponent() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <Stack direction="column" spacing={2} sx={{ gap: 2 }}>
      <div className={classes.item}>Item 1</div>
      <div className={classes.item}>Item 2</div>
      <div className={classes.item}>Item 3</div>
      <div className={classes.item}>Item 4</div>
      <div className={classes.item}>Item 5</div>
      <div className={classes.gap} />
    </Stack>
  );
}
```

Comment: This solution doesn't work still spacing area is white may be there is some problem  in Stack component. isn't it?

Comment: I have edited the post. try the component I put under `example` first before you do your iteration. It works when I tried it